# Kafka stream: PolicyViolationException: Topic replication factor must be 3

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I'm currently building an application that writes to a kafka topic and listens to that very same topic to generate a `ktable` from it and materialize it into a store. The code i'm running is based on the following [sample](https://github.com/spring-tips/spring-cloud-stream-kafka-streams). I pretty much copied most of it (all except PageViewEventSource) and refactored the names to my use case. I also updated my `application.properties` with the keys used in the sample.

When running the application i get the following errors:

```
2020-02-12 17:54:31.982 ERROR 69005 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.i.InternalTopicManager         : stream-thread [restartedMain] Unexpected error during topic creation for pairing-events-pcmv-changelog.
Error message was: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.PolicyViolationException: Topic replication factor must be 3
2020-02-12 17:54:31.986 ERROR 69005 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread         : stream-thread [pairing-events-2d949c85-df82-4961-a849-6c6e079edf9c-StreamThread-1] Encountered the following unexpected Kafka exception during processing, this usually indicate Streams internal errors:

org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Could not create topic pairing-events-pcmv-changelog.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.InternalTopicManager.makeReady(InternalTopicManager.java:148) ~[kafka-streams-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsPartitionAssignor.prepareTopic(StreamsPartitionAssignor.java:1049) ~[kafka-streams-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsPartitionAssignor.assign(StreamsPartitionAssignor.java:635) ~[kafka-streams-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.performAssignment(ConsumerCoordinator.java:424) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.onJoinLeader(AbstractCoordinator.java:622) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.access$1100(AbstractCoordinator.java:107) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$JoinGroupResponseHandler.handle(AbstractCoordinator.java:544) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$JoinGroupResponseHandler.handle(AbstractCoordinator.java:527) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:978) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:958) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture$1.onSuccess(RequestFuture.java:204) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.fireSuccess(RequestFuture.java:167) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.complete(RequestFuture.java:127) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler.fireCompletion(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:578) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.firePendingCompletedRequests(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:388) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:294) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:233) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:212) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:415) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:358) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:353) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1251) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1216) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1201) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollRequests(StreamThread.java:963) ~[kafka-streams-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:859) ~[kafka-streams-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:819) ~[kafka-streams-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:788) ~[kafka-streams-2.3.1.jar:na]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.PolicyViolationException: Topic replication factor must be 3

2020-02-12 17:54:31.986  INFO 69005 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread         : stream-thread [pairing-events-2d949c85-df82-4961-a849-6c6e079edf9c-StreamThread-1] State transition from PARTITIONS_REVOKED to PENDING_SHUTDOWN
2020-02-12 17:54:31.986  INFO 69005 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread         : stream-thread [pairing-events-2d949c85-df82-4961-a849-6c6e079edf9c-StreamThread-1] Shutting down
2020-02-12 17:54:31.986  INFO 69005 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=pairing-events-2d949c85-df82-4961-a849-6c6e079edf9c-StreamThread-1-restore-consumer, groupId=null] Unsubscribed all topics or patterns and assigned partitions
2020-02-12 17:54:31.986  INFO 69005 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=pairing-events-2d949c85-df82-4961-a849-6c6e079edf9c-StreamThread-1-producer] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms.
2020-02-12 17:54:31.991  INFO 69005 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread         : stream-thread [pairing-events-2d949c85-df82-4961-a849-6c6e079edf9c-StreamThread-1] State transition from PENDING_SHUTDOWN to DEAD
2020-02-12 17:54:31.991  INFO 69005 --- [-StreamThread-1] org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams    : stream-client [pairing-events-2d949c85-df82-4961-a849-6c6e079edf9c] State transition from REBALANCING to ERROR
2020-02-12 17:54:31.991 ERROR 69005 --- [-StreamThread-1] org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams    : stream-client [pairing-events-2d949c85-df82-4961-a849-6c6e079edf9c] All stream threads have died. The instance will be in error state and should be closed.
2020-02-12 17:54:31.991  INFO 69005 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread         : stream-thread [pairing-events-2d949c85-df82-4961-a849-6c6e079edf9c-StreamThread-1] Shutdown complete
Exception in thread "pairing-events-2d949c85-df82-4961-a849-6c6e079edf9c-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Could not create topic pairing-events-pcmv-changelog.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.InternalTopicManager.makeReady(InternalTopicManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsPartitionAssignor.prepareTopic(StreamsPartitionAssignor.java:1049)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsPartitionAssignor.assign(StreamsPartitionAssignor.java:635)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.performAssignment(ConsumerCoordinator.java:424)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.onJoinLeader(AbstractCoordinator.java:622)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.access$1100(AbstractCoordinator.java:107)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$JoinGroupResponseHandler.handle(AbstractCoordinator.java:544)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$JoinGroupResponseHandler.handle(AbstractCoordinator.java:527)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:978)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:958)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture$1.onSuccess(RequestFuture.java:204)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.fireSuccess(RequestFuture.java:167)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.complete(RequestFuture.java:127)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler.fireCompletion(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:578)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.firePendingCompletedRequests(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:388)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:294)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:233)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:212)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:415)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:358)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:353)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1251)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1216)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1201)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollRequests(StreamThread.java:963)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:859)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:819)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:788)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.PolicyViolationException: Topic replication factor must be 3
```

Any clues how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your broker setup requires a minimum replication factor of 3.

You can set the `... topic.replication-factor` property for the binding.

See [Consumer Properties](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#kafka-consumer-properties) in the binder documentation.

Comment: I've added `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.default.consumer.topic.replication-factor=3` and `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.replication-factor=3` to `application.properties` and still get same error. @GaryRussel

Comment: this one worked `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.replication.factor=3`

Answer (score 0):

I also observed the `PolicyViolationException: Topic replication factor must be 3` recently.

What I did was add the following to the .properties file of my relevant spring cloud services:

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.replicationFactor=3
```

That seems to have fixed it! :)

In my case, I was using a kafka provider (confluent) and by default the `replication.factor` is set to 3 when creating a new topic.